# DocuSign how to save the Private key as a .PEM file

Tags: docusignapi, pem

From the JSON Web Token Bearer Grant guide, it was recommended that I should save the Private key as a .PEM file

> Note: If you’re working with sample code from one of the SDKs, save
>   the Private key as a .PEM file. The SDK is configured to read the
>   private key value from a file with this extension.

So now that I have generated my private key:

```
 ----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY---- 
****
 ----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How do I save this as a .PEM file, is it simply just pasting this private key into a notepad and instead of saving to a .txt file I should change the extension to .PEM?

Also is there any security reason why I should save the private key as a .pem instead of .txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, what counts is what is inside the file, not the extension.

So you can either rename `docusignPrivateKey.txt` to `docusignPrivateKey.pem` or leave it as `.txt`